# Kotlin Coroutines withTimeout not throwing TimeoutCancellationException when proguard enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, kotlin-coroutines

When proguard is enabled withTimeout does not seem to throw TimeoutCancellationException.

The following code works well without shrinking or with R8. `withTimeout` firing TimeoutCancellationException after 3s as expected.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()).launch {
                try {
                    withTimeout(3000) {
                      delay(4000)
                    }
                } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.message)
                }
            }
```

But when I enable proguard the exception is not thrown anymore and the `delay` suspend function completes normally.

I use the following rules in my proguard-rule.pro :

```
-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.flow.**inlined**
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}

# Most of volatile fields are updated with AFU and should not be mangled
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

I use the following versions :

- AS gradle plugin version : 3.5.1
- Kotlin version : 1.3.50
- Kotlin coroutines versions :

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
```

As anyone experienced the same issue ? Am I missing a proguard rule ?

Thanks